# Auto-Resizing Custom Views with Multi-Line UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, custom-controls

I’d like to create some reusable custom UI components to be used in my such as the following `UIView` containing two labels. The labels may, depending on the content, be multi-line, and I provided some constraints for upper and lower margins. The views are added to my layout mainly inside `UIStackView`s using Interface Builder or programmatically. Trouble here is, that the height of the views is not calculated correctly in runtime, cutting off a portion on the bottom of each view, particularly when there are multiple lines.

There is obviously some conceptual issue that I have not been able to figure out yet, and probably getting this two-label example right would help me getting a better understanding.

I commented out the overall height constraint, which I thought was necessary, but with that uncommented I see only the top line of the second label.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TwoLabelView: UIView {

    var topMargin: CGFloat = 11.0
    var verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 3.0
    var bottomMargin: CGFloat = 8.0

    @IBInspectable var firstLabelText: String = "" { didSet { updateView() } }
    @IBInspectable var secondLabelText: String = "" { didSet { updateView() } }

    var viewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    var firstLabel: UILabel!
    var secondLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {

        firstLabel = UILabel()
        firstLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
        firstLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        secondLabel = UILabel()
        secondLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
        secondLabel.numberOfLines = 20
        secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

        addSubview(firstLabel)
        addSubview(secondLabel)

        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {

        firstLabel.text = firstLabelText
        secondLabel.text = secondLabelText

        firstLabel.sizeToFit()
        secondLabel.sizeToFit()
        viewHeight = getHeight()

        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstLabel .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        removeConstraints(constraints)

        if self.isHidden == false {
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: topMargin))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: firstLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: verticalSpacing))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))
            self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondLabel, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: bottomMargin))
            //self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: viewHeight))
        }

        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    func getHeight() -> CGFloat {

        return topMargin
            + firstLabel.frame.height
            + verticalSpacing
            + secondLabel.frame.height
            + bottomMargin
    }

    override open var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: getHeight())
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you put the `setupViews` and constraints code inside `override func layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: It seems like `updateView()` is called before `layoutSubviews()` causing an 'unexpectedly found nil' error when trying to assign text values to the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...

First, you don't need to keep re-creating the constraints. Create them once when you setup the labels.

Second, you want to use the constraints to let auto-layout control the sizing - that's what they're for.

Third, auto-sizing multiline-labels can be tricky. Well, a better word might be *confounding*! For auto-layout to render and size the text in the label, it has to *start* with a width. Unfortunately, the common scenario is having the label's width controlled by something else - its superview, a stack view, etc. BUT... you also want the width of the label to control or *"push out the sides"* of its superview.

So, you need to make sure the label has a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. Of course, you don't want to hard-code that - defeats the purpose of creating a flexible control.

The trick, from my experience anyway, is to ***force*** auto-layout to run a couple passes... and set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` sorta "in the middle" of the process.

Try this out, and see if you get what you're going for:

```
//
//  TwoLabelView.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/2/17.
//

class FixAutoLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if(self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != self.bounds.size.width) {
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width
        }
    }

}

@IBDesignable class TwoLabelView: UIView {

    var topMargin: CGFloat = 11.0
    var verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 3.0
    var bottomMargin: CGFloat = 8.0

    @IBInspectable var firstLabelText: String = "" { didSet { updateView() } }
    @IBInspectable var secondLabelText: String = "" { didSet { updateView() } }

    var firstLabel: FixAutoLabel!
    var secondLabel: FixAutoLabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpView()
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        setUpView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView() {

        firstLabel = FixAutoLabel()
        firstLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFontWeightBold)
        firstLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        firstLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail

        secondLabel = FixAutoLabel()
        secondLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
        secondLabel.numberOfLines = 20
        secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail

        addSubview(firstLabel)
        addSubview(secondLabel)

        // we're going to set the constraints
        firstLabel .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // pin both labels' left-edges to left-edge of self
        firstLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        secondLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // pin both labels' right-edges to right-edge of self
        firstLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        secondLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // pin firstLabel to the top of self + topMargin (padding)
        firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: topMargin).isActive = true

        // pin top of secondLabel to bottom of firstLabel + verticalSpacing
        secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: verticalSpacing).isActive = true

        // pin bottom of self to bottom of secondLabel + bottomMargin (padding)
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: bottomMargin).isActive = true

        // colors are just for debugging so we can see the frames of the labels
        firstLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = .green

        // call common "refresh" func
        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {

        firstLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.width
        secondLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.width

        firstLabel.text = firstLabelText
        secondLabel.text = secondLabelText

        firstLabel.sizeToFit()
        secondLabel.sizeToFit()

        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    }

    override open var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        // just has to have SOME intrinsic content size defined
        // this will be overridden by the constraints
        return CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
}
```